# Use Node.js to Edit HTML Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I have searched around quiet a bit but failed to find a solution to my specific scenario.

I have used Cheerio module to parse a bunch of html pages, ut what i couldnt do is edit or add HTML code to the parsed html. I would like to automatically edit headings and links for each page by their Class or ID and save that HTML page the way its been edited. If it could be done with just Cherrio/FS, thatd be awesome, but if I require some other modules for this task, kindly enlighten me.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.* To answer your question, however, yes, you can probably do it with just `fs` and `cheerio`.

Comment: Thanks @royhowie for your response. I apologize, im new to stackoverflow, ill keep that in mind. If its possible to edit code with cheerio, how? I coudlnt find any methods to be able to replace a tag text or anything similar! so far all i have been able to do it scrape info from the file.

Comment: [`.remove`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#remove-selector-)? [`.text( [textString] )`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#text-textstring-)?

Comment: yup that did the trick. I just edited the loaded cheerio object and then rewrote the file using fs.writeFile! Thanks :) @royhowie